# Is it possible to use a UIRefreshControl in a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a UIPageViewController that vertically displays ViewControllers. However, I need to refresh content when the user swipes down on the top ViewController in the UIPageViewController with a UIRefreshControl. Is this possible? I've tried using the UIScrollView built into the UIPageViewController but I've yet to have success.

I'm using Xamarin iOS but answers in swift or objective-c work just as well.

Comment: What type of ViewControllers are you using in the page controller?

Comment: if the UIPageViewController is vertical and you want to refresh on swipe down that wont be a good idea how would OS knows which view should respond to the event more over it will probably be very bad experience for the user

Comment: The UIPageViewController has normal UIViewControllers. The OS might be able to know due to the fact that it's the first ViewController but I guess I could implement my own custom refresher

Comment: Were you able to put a refresh control on UIPageViewController?